# XElement - joining multiple elements under one

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml, xelement

I am having trouble combining two XML's into one.

First XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<SalesOrderHeader>
  <SOFields>
    <CompanyName>company</CompanyName>
    <joinKey>c9e60279-6759-eb11-a2e4-00155d0a9c55</joinKey>
    <SalesId>SO100001</SalesId>
  </SOFields>
</SalesOrderHeader>
```

Second XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<SalesOrderLines>
  <SOL>
    <CompanyName>company</CompanyName>
    <SOLUniqueKey>fe695341-6959-eb11-a2e4-00155d0a9c55</SOLUniqueKey>
    <ItemId>12345</ItemId>
    <ItemName>ItemName1</ItemName>
    <SalesOrderJoinKey>c9e60279-6759-eb11-a2e4-00155d0a9c55</SalesOrderJoinKey>
    <SalesAmount>100.0000</SalesAmount>
    <SalesPrice>20.0000</SalesPrice>
  </SOL>
    <SOL>
    <CompanyName>company</CompanyName>
    <SOLUniqueKey>ff695342-6959-eb11-a2e4-00155d0a9c55</SOLUniqueKey>
    <ItemId>34597</ItemId>
    <ItemName>ItemName2</ItemName>
    <SalesOrderJoinKey>c9e60279-6759-eb11-a2e4-00155d0a9c55</SalesOrderJoinKey>
    <SalesAmount>5.0000</SalesAmount>
    <SalesPrice>10.0000</SalesPrice>
  </SOL>
    <SOL>
    <CompanyName>company</CompanyName>
    <SOLUniqueKey>fz695343-6959-eb11-a2e4-00155d0a9c55</SOLUniqueKey>
    <ItemId>65874</ItemId>
    <ItemName>ItemName3</ItemName>
    <SalesOrderJoinKey>c9e60279-6759-eb11-a2e4-00155d0a9c55</SalesOrderJoinKey>
    <SalesAmount>10.0000</SalesAmount>
    <SalesPrice>24.0000</SalesPrice>
  </SOL>
</SalesOrderLines>
```

These two XML files are formed with the XElement.
I am trying to join both of these files like this:

```
var newSOH = new XElement("SalesOrder",
                    from c in xmlElement.Element("SalesOrderHeader").Elements("SOFields")
                    join o in xmlElementSOL.Element("SalesOrderLines").Elements("SOL")
                           on (string)c.Element("joinKey") equals
                              (string)o.Element("SalesOrderJoinKey")
```

The join elements are **joinKey** on SalesOrderHeader and **SalesOrderJoinKey** on SOL.

However, this join results in "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

The ultimate result is that all of the elements in the second XML (SalesOrderLInes) file would be under one Sales order header, like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<SalesOrder>
<SalesOrderHeader>
  <SOFields>
    <CompanyName>company</CompanyName>
    <joinKey>c9e60279-6759-eb11-a2e4-00155d0a9c55</joinKey>
    <SalesId>SO100001</SalesId>
  </SOFields>
 </SalesOrderHeader>
<SalesOrderLines>
    <SOL>
    <CompanyName>company</CompanyName>
    <SOLUniqueKey>fe695341-6959-eb11-a2e4-00155d0a9c55</SOLUniqueKey>
    <ItemId>12345</ItemId>
    <ItemName>ItemName1</ItemName>
    <SalesOrderJoinKey>c9e60279-6759-eb11-a2e4-00155d0a9c55</SalesOrderJoinKey>
    <SalesAmount>100.0000</SalesAmount>
    <SalesPrice>20.0000</SalesPrice>
  </SOL>
    <SOL>
    <CompanyName>company</CompanyName>
    <SOLUniqueKey>ff695342-6959-eb11-a2e4-00155d0a9c55</SOLUniqueKey>
    <ItemId>34597</ItemId>
    <ItemName>ItemName2</ItemName>
    <SalesOrderJoinKey>c9e60279-6759-eb11-a2e4-00155d0a9c55</SalesOrderJoinKey>
    <SalesAmount>5.0000</SalesAmount>
    <SalesPrice>10.0000</SalesPrice>
  </SOL>
    <SOL>
    <CompanyName>company</CompanyName>
    <SOLUniqueKey>fz695343-6959-eb11-a2e4-00155d0a9c55</SOLUniqueKey>
    <ItemId>65874</ItemId>
    <ItemName>ItemName3</ItemName>
    <SalesOrderJoinKey>c9e60279-6759-eb11-a2e4-00155d0a9c55</SalesOrderJoinKey>
    <SalesAmount>10.0000</SalesAmount>
    <SalesPrice>24.0000</SalesPrice>
  </SOL>
</SalesOrderLines>
</SalesOrder>
```

I have tried to follow this example https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/linq/join-two-collections but from what I have read in other posts this method will not work for me.

Thanks for any advice you can give.

Answer (score 0):

Given that you have parsed each XML into an `XElement`, it already reference the root element so you don't need to mention root element anymore in the query:

```
var newSOH = new XElement("SalesOrder",
        from c in xmlElement.Elements("SOFields")
        join o in xmlElementSOL.Elements("SOL")
                on (string)c.Element("joinKey") equals
                    (string)o.Element("SalesOrderJoinKey")
        select new List<XElement>(){
            new XElement("SalesOrderHeader", c),
            new XElement("SalesOrderLines", o)
        });


System.Console.WriteLine(newSOH.ToString());
```

**<kbd>[dotnetfiddle demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/GXRlqu)</kbd>**

Comment: @Ruslan any problem with this approach?